# How to migrate from Enterprice edition to community edition?

Tags: magento

I have a store running in magento Enterprise edition, would like to migrate to Community Edition, can you please suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this from Professional edition to community and there is no way to really migrate. You basically have to export all of your products, import. Install a new copy of the extensions (very often there is a enterprise specific extension), reconfig. And then copy over the cms and blocks, categories and attribute sets.

Some stuff you can do using tables. But its really best to just manually chunk things in and out.